# When I push a project to Github, I have the files of the oldest commit, why?

Tags: git, github

I have a project on local and I would like to push the project on a github repository
On local I have many commits

To push on github I use the following commande lines:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git`

`git pull origin master`

`git push origin master`

It works but I have the first version of the project corresponds to the oldest commit

When I use the following command:
`git branch -vv --all`

I have:

```
 master    4da82c9 first commit
* old-state 35dd8a0 last commit
```

I forget something but I don't know what.

Comment: can you mention what is the expected outcome and what is the current outcome?

Comment: I have the first version of the project corresponds to the oldest commit and I would like the last version of the project

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: On the old-state branch
nothing to validate, the working copy is clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `pull origin master` while you are on  `old-state` would update  old-state only, not `master`.

At least, checkout (or [switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)) to `master` first.

```
git checkout master
# or with Git 2.23+
git switch master
```

Then:

```
git push -u origin master
```